# Number of users logged in Business Objects 5.x Version

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to create audit report for number of users logged in business objects.

I have read from Blogs , this version is not supported with Query Builders, not able to connect through query Builder.
 I tried to run these scripts to identify number of users logged in BO, in

MS access Query:

```
SELECT * FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS

WHERE SI_PARENTID=23 AND SI_NAME = 'COMPANY A'
```

I have also found this script in SAP blogs

```
SELECT count (SI_NAME)  FROM CI_SYSTEMOBJECTS

WHERE SI_LASTLOGONTIME> '2013.02.14.00.00.01' AND SI_KIND = 'Connection'
```

Error for both queries:

> Tables/objects do not exist

I Guess this is only supported for newer versions of BO repository. Any one could help me to create similar scripts for BO repository for 5X version of Busienss objects. I am not familiar with older version tables and could not build query.

> Note: I want to query number of users logged into Business objects at
>   a given period
>
> Database: BO repository
>
> SQL : MS Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the number or list of active users is query-able in BO prior to XI.  You can get the list of active users in the Admin Console, however.  The number of active users is displayed in the status bar, and the list of active users is available on the Site Properties tab -- click on "List of logged in users".

If you want historical connection info, then that will be available in the auditing tables, provided that you have a license for Auditor and it is enabled in Admin Console.

Note that this will not capture users logged in to Full Client (aka DeskI); only those logged in to Infoview.